# Check if field exists in CosmosDB JSON with SQL - nodeJS

Tags: sql, json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure CosmosDB to store documents (JSON).

I am trying to query all documents that contain the field `"abc"`, and not return the documents that do not have the field `"abc"`. For example, return the first object below and not the second

```
{
    "abc": "123"
}

{
    "jkl": "098"
}
```

I am trying to use the following code:

```
client.queryDocuments(
collectionUrl,
`SELECT r.id, r.authToken.instagram,r.userName FROM root r WHERE r.abc`
)
```

I assumed the above would check if `abc` exists similar to `if (r.abc) {}`

I have tried using `WHERE r.abc IS NOT NULL`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

All you need to do is change your query to

```
SELECT r.id, r.authToken.instagram,r.userName FROM root r WHERE r.abc != null
```

or

```
SELECT r.id, r.authToken.instagram,r.userName FROM root r WHERE r.abc <> null
```

Both operators work (tested on the Data Explorer)

Comment: does this not check for the string `null` - thus assuming `"abc":"null"` does not exist? - Or at least that `"abc": null` does not exist, rather than that `"abc"` stricly exists?

Comment: No this is checking whether the value is null (not string "null", but just null) OR whether the property named `abc` is part of the json body.

Comment: ah ok thanks - is there a way to strictly check if the property name is part of the json? Thus ignore if the value is null too?

Comment: Nothing that I can find in predefined functions. You would have to write a UDF yourself. Even `IS_DEFINED()` will return if the value is `null`.

Comment: Ok - thanks, I will just make sure that "abc" never contains null.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. To determine if the field actually exists, you need to do what @ARowan said

Comment: This accepted answer is not correct.

Answer (score 87):

If you want to know if a field exists you should use the IS_DEFINED("FieldName")
If you want to know if the field's value has a value the
FieldName != null or
FieldName <> null (apparently)

I use variations of this in production:

```sql
SELECT c.FieldName
FROM c 
WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.FieldName)
```

Comment: IS_DEFINED is particularly useful to find documents that don't have some field populated, when the serialization ignores the null fields. In this case, IS_NULL doesn't work.

Comment: I'm writing a query right now to give me a list of records which haven't had an analytic calculated on them.  It's great.

Answer (score 21):

Add the `NOT` operator in the SQL query to negate.

```
SELECT r.id, r.authToken.instagram,r.userName 
FROM root r 
WHERE NOT IS_DEFINED(r.abc)
```

to include all entries where the FieldName `abc` doesn't exist.